# NLog setup for ASP.NET core by extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I want to use NLog in ASP.NET Core.

Environment:

- `.NET 6`
- `NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.1.5` including `NLog.Extensions.Logging v5.1.0` (both latest)

I have added this piece of code to use NLog provider configured from the `appsettings.json` but the logging does not work.

```
var config = builder.Configuration.GetSection("NLog");
builder.Logging.AddNLog(config);
```

To ensure there it's not a problem with the configuration itself, I have tried this instead, and it works.

```
var config = builder.Configuration.GetSection("NLog");
LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config);
builder.Logging.AddNLog();
```

I would expect these to be identical. What is the purpose of the overload of `AddNLog` accepting `IConfiguration` otherwise?

Comment: It is only if you want to override the default Host-Configuration, that you use `AddNLog(IConfiguration)`, else just use `AddNLogWeb()` or `UseNLog()` which will automatically load from the default Host-Configuration.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6